# Selenium get only 1 in multi elements need to collect

Tags: kotlin, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, getelementsbyclassname

as the question means, the driver->findElements just get 1 `div.classnameA` but the inspector show 22 `.classnameA` items. I also pause the process, using `Thread.sleep(15)` waiting for page full load because the AJAX request. So Kotlin lines so simple.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/main/kotlin/org/drivers/chromedriver")
val driver = ChromeDriver()
driver.get("https://somethingcool.com")
try {
   Thread.sleep(10000)
} finally {
  var e = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".classnameA"))
  println(e.size)
}
```

the interesting thing is, if I change to findElement with `.classnameB`, it returns all 5 elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things regarding the shared code:

1. From Selenium version 4.6, you don't need to manage browser binaries anymore. Please see [this link](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) for more information. So you can remove the first line.
2. In general, Thread.sleep() calls for waiting for elements are discouraged, and you should use one of the Selenium waits - preferably explicit wait. Please see [this link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) for more information.

Having said that, assuming the provided locator is correct, you can do something like this in Kotlin:

```
var wait: Wait<WebDriver> = FluentWait(driver)
    .withTimear wait: Wait<WebDriver> = FluentWait(driver)
    .without(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException::class.java)

var elements: List<WebElement> = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".classnameA")))
```

You can also try e.g. [numberOfElementsToBe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/235bc94f6b09b37328acdaecfa7837a2726df757/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L1004) or other methods to wait for the elements as well.

If the code still fails to find elements, I suggest trying out a different locator strategy, e.g. `className`.

Comment: thank you for the numberOfElementsToBe. The solution i get is not waiting, but scrolling. because the web is rendered by javascript, so element dynamically appear just when it was scroll to its position.

Comment: Then you could try to scroll down first by casting the driver to JavaScriptexecutor. For reference, please see "How to scroll down to an element in Selenium until it is visible" on https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-scroll-tutorial